# Can we create transit vlan on Virtual Server hosted on IBM Cloud?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Something similar as with Vyatta  Gateway is their possible to have the transit Vlan on VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not create transit vlan on virtual server as you do with vyatta gateway, because a Network Gateway is sized to handle the routing load for multiple VLANs and the virtual server no.

For more information you can review these documents:

https://www.ibm.com/cloud/virtual-servers

https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/topic/gateways

https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/learning/network-gateway-devices-vyatta